# How remain pairs by below criteria? (explained my criteria)

Tags: r, database, dplyr

While doing my data work I have this problem.
Data is as below,

```
row_number      var1 var2
1               1921 16
2               1922 16
3               1921 17
4               1922 17
5               1703 29
6               1704 29
7               1705 29
8               1703 30
9               1704 30
10              1705 30
11              1703 31
12              1704 31
13              1705 31
```

I want to make pairs by only using unique var1 and unique var2.

In other words, 1~4 rows can be a group and I only need to remain 1st and 4th column. And, 5~13 rows can be an another group and I only need to remain this pair (1703 29, 1704 30, 1705 31). That is, I want to have this outcome

```
row_number      var1 var2
1               1921 16
4               1922 17
5               1703 29
9               1704 30
13              1705 31
```

I have much more observations.

Comment: If 5-13 is another group, why is 9 in included?

Comment: From 5th to 13th rows (total 9 rows) is a another group

Comment: I understand that, but the number of elements in first one i.e. 1-4 is 4, from 5-9 it is 5

Comment: 5~13= > number of elements is 9. (because number of unique var1 is three and number of unique var is three) => 3*3=>9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data is in a dataframe named `d`.  Then

```
out <- data.frame(row_number = NA, var1 = NA, var2 = NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  if (!(d[i, "var1" ] %in% out[, "var1"]) & !(d[i, "var2"] %in% out[, "var2"])) {
    out <- rbind(out, d[i,])
  }
}
out <- out[-1, ]
out
#    row_number var1 var2
# 2           1 1921   16
# 4           4 1922   17
# 5           5 1703   29
# 9           9 1704   30
# 13         13 1705   31
```

gives you your desired result by iterating through rows of `d` and extracting only rows where neither `var1` nor `var2` has previously appeared in the output dataframe.

Comment: I have much more observations. It does not working for my long data sets. I am trying to understand your logic

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "it does not work." You may need to clarify *your* logic (but please do not write that in the comments -- do so by editing your question above).

Comment: Sorry. never mind last my comment. BUT here is problem.
In output and data "d", both should have same  number of unique var1  and var 2.

Comment: So, there should not be duplicated ones in each column in outcome.